# How to compute difference of each point of a data series from the first point?

Tags: matlab, difference, array-difference

i have signature time-series data for x-y coordinates as given below(for one file)...

```
  x     y
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12300 9400 
12300 9400 
12300 9400 
12300 9400 
12300 9400 
12300 9400
12300 9300 
12300 9300...
```

I would like to compute the (difference) x-y coordinates relative to first point of the series...
Could anyone guide me how do i compute it in matlab? Any suitable function or piece of code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's much easier to help if you remove some of the duplicates (you could easily make the dataset half the size and still ask the same question. Also, it helps a lot if you include the desired result (which again is simpler if you have fewer rows.

Comment: Thanks sir...i got the point..

Comment: Did I answer the question in the first comment? If so I'll post it as an answer so that the question doesn't appear unanswered. Which one solved the problem? Or was it the second comment, and you'll update the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To subtract the first row from an entire array, use `bsxfun`:

```
A = [
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12200 9400 
12300 9400 
12300 9400 
12300 9400
12300 9300 
12300 9300]

differenceToFirstPoint = bsxfun(@minus, A, A(1,:));

%# to calculate the norm:
normOfDifference = sqrt( sum( differenceToFirstPoint.^2, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your question is, starting from a set of points `(x1,y1);(x2,y2);...(xn,yn)` how to get `(0,0);(x2-x1,y2-y1);...(xn-x1,yn-y1)`

Quick solution: if `a` is a N-by-2 array containing your data, then

```
b=a; b(:,1)=b(:,1)-b(1,1); b(:,2)=b(:,2)-b(1,2);
```

If your question was about how to *import* the data from a CSV file or something else, it is completely different.